# Is the 28 Weeks Later Flash Game still available?

Tags: video-games, 28-weeks-later, 28-days-later

Does anyone know if the Flash Game made to promote the film 28 Weeks Later is still available and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Can you describe the game a little for help with trying to google info about it?

Comment: Honestly, this question is on the edge of being off-topic, falling under the area of "shopping" questions, but I think that it hits a grey area. You're not asking for where to find the best deal, but rather whether it still exists and/or is officially maintained.

Comment: My _god_ I hope so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean [this flash game?](http://web.archive.org/web/20081123042824/http://games.scifi.uk.com/28weekslater/) Seems pretty bad, but there you go.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: back in 2015, when I answered this question, the link was active, browsers had Flash players, and the game worked. Downvoting this on 2023 just because the link doesn't work _now_ seems unfair. But you do you, I guess.